# How to copy files while maintaining original folder structure?

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I wonder if I could help to do the following:

Search the PC (all units) all autocad files (* .DWG) and word (* .doc) and copy them to a new route from my server; the first time it is run must be a FULL and then just changed the date of FULL files are copied.

I have tried to use the following:

```
mkdir \\server1\j$\bk_user\%computername%\FULL\%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%\a_ofim\

FORFILES /P C:\ /S /M *.doc* /C "cmd /c COPY @file \\server1\j$\bk_user\%computername%\FULL\%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%\a_ofima\"

FORFILES /P C:\ /S /M *.dwg /C "cmd /c COPY @file \\server1\j$\bk_user\%computername%\FULL\%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%\a_ofim\"
```

The point is that I do not know how to:

1. Search all hard drives, my current code only searches drive C: (I
   was thinking of placing a line with "if exist D: \ goto diskD" and
   so for each disc, but I'm not sure if there is another more
   efficiently
2. That every time you find and copy the file, copy it maintaining
   its original folder structure, because then no one knows where it
   came from that file because the places all together.

I hope you can help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I search all hard drives?

To enumerate all your local drives, use the following batch file (GetDrives.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  set _drive=%%d
  echo !_drive!
  rem add search code here
  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> GetDrives.cmd
C:
add search code here
D:
add search code here
E:
add search code here
F:
add search code here
```

---

To skip DVD/CD drives, use the following batch file (GetDrives.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype  ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  if not [%%e]==[5] (
    set _drive=%%d
    echo !_drive!
    echo add search code here
    )
  )
endlocal
```

Example output (Drive d: is my DVD drive):

```
> GetDrives.cmd
C:
add search code here
E:
add search code here
F:
add search code here

>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation

Comment: Thank you!! this code if it is very useful, but I have a question ... How can I make not record or detect network drives? Because I just want to look in the local disks ...

Comment: Eureka!!   @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype  ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  if not [%%e]==[4] (
 if not [%%e]==[5] (
    set _drive=%%d
    echo !_drive!
    echo add search code here
    )
    )
  )
endlocal

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to transfer that kind of data while maintaining the folder structure is through Robocopy.

With Robocopy you can also use multi threading support to help speed up your transfers.

EXAMPLE:
Robocopy C:\ *.dwg \\myserver\backup\users_C_Drive /MT:4

That will keep the folder structure.  You can get fancy later and add in custom excludes for temp files and folders to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an exact duplicate, use the following version (which is equivalent to adding /E and /PURGE:

```
robocopy c:\test d:\test /MIR
```

If all you want to do is copy the directories and subdirectories including empty ones, use

```
robocopy c:\test d:\test /E
```

It is the backslash on the E option that was getting you.

To learn more about Robocopy here is a handy search:

http://www.google.com?q=robocopy+syntax

From my post at [Robocopy - Copy directory into another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1212349/robocopy-copy-directory-into-another-directory/1212364#1212364)