# Robocopy copy directory instead of just its content

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

Simple question, no obvious solution. I have a folder called Test on the C drive (C:\Test). I have a folder called Test 2 on the D drive (D:\Test2). I want to robocopy the Test folder to the Test2 folder.

If I `robocopy /e C:\Test D:\Test2\` I end up copying the content of folder Test instead of the folder and its content (however, if, in Bash, I `cp -a folder1 folder2/`, I get folder1 in folder2). D:\Test2 will not have a folder called Test (and its content). It will have the content of folder Test, and the actual first folder is not copied.

What am I doing wrong? [Robocopy - Copy directory into another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1212349/robocopy-copy-directory-into-another-directory) does not address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the source folder name to the destination path:

```
robocopy /e C:\Test D:\Test2\Test
```

Comment: Not beautiful but does the trick. Thank you.